# Java Polymorphism - Specific Example

Tags: java, polymorphism

I've got some problems with the following example (to be more precise, with one specific line). Here's the code (question follows afterwards):

```
public class Up
{
    public void cc(Up u) {System.out.println("A");}
    public void cc(Middle m) {System.out.println("B");}
}

public class Middle extends Up
{
    public void cc(Up u) {System.out.println("C");}
    public void cc(Down d) {System.out.println("D");}
}

public class Down extends Middle
{
    public void cc(Up u) {System.out.println("E");}
    public void cc(Middle m) {System.out.println("F");}
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Up uu = new Up();
        Up pp = new Middle();
        Down dd = new Down();

        uu.cc(pp); // "A"
        uu.cc(dd); // "B"
        pp.cc(pp); // "C"
        pp.cc(dd); // "B"
        dd.cc(pp); // "E"
        dd.cc(dd); // "D"
    }
}
```

Now `uu.cc(pp);` and `uu.cc(dd);` are pretty obvious, because uu is an instance of `Up` and `pp` "looks like" an `Up` aswell (at compile time). The most fitting method for `dd` is `cc(Middle m)` as `dd` is an instance of `Down` which inherits from `Middle`.

The lines I've got the most problems with are `pp.cc(dd);` and `dd.cc(dd)`.
I'm really a bit confused about which method is chosen when and how these things are determined upon compiliation or at runtime.
I'd be glad if someone could help me understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the method *signature* is chosen at compile time based on the compile-time types of the expressions involved, and the *implementation* is chosen at execution time, based on the actual implementation just of the *target* of the method.

So at compile time, `pp.cc(dd)` tries to find a match for `Up.cc(Down)`. The most specific match is `Up.cc(Middle)`, so that's what ends up in the compiled code. Now at *execution* time, the implementation of that will be `Up.cc(Middle)` because `Middle` doesn't override that method signature. Hence it prints "B".

Now at compile time, `dd.cc(dd)` tries to find a match for `Down.cc(Down).` There are two relevant choices here - either `Middle.cc(Down)` which matches the *parameter* exactly, or `Down.cc(Middle)` which matches the *target type* exactly. The compiler prefers `Middle.cc(Down)`. At execution time, again that method hasn't been overridden in `Down`, so it prints "D".

The relevant bit of the specification for overload resolution is 15.12, and in particular [15.12.2 - determining the method signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2).

Answer (score 0):

In `pp.cc(dd);` the compiler has to choose in between methods belonging to the type of pp, `Up`. The best fit is `cc(Middle m)`. You don't override this method in `Middle`, so runtime the `Up` method is called.

In `dd.cc(dd)` the compiler chooses in between methods belonging to `Down`, `Middle` or `Up` since `dd` is a `Down`. `Middle`'s method `cc(Down)` exactly matches the type of `dd` and is chosen.

So, compile-time the choice is made based on the declared type of the variable, and the most fitting method signature. Then normal override rules apply runtime.